# My GPU has 2 multiprocessors with 48 CUDA cores each. What does this mean?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

My GPU has 2 multiprocessors with 48 CUDA cores each. Does this mean that I can execute 96 thread blocks in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't.

From chapter 4 of the CUDA C programming guide:

> The number of blocks and warps that can reside and be processed together on the multiprocessor for a given kernel depends on the amount of registers and shared memory used by the kernel and the amount of registers and shared memory available on the multiprocessor. There are also a maximum number of resident blocks and a maximum number of resident warps per multiprocessor. These limits as well the amount of registers and shared memory available on the multiprocessor are a function of the compute capability of the device and are given in Appendix F. If there are not enough registers or shared memory available per multiprocessor to process at least one block, the kernel will fail to launch.

Get the guide at: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf

To check the limits for your specific device compile and execute the cudaDeviceQuery example from the SDK.

So far the maximum number of resident blocks per multiprocessor is the same across all compute capabilities and is equal to 8.

Comment: From your answer I understand i could executed 96 blocks if there are register and shared memory available

Comment: @pQB There is also the part of the maximum number of resident blocks and a maximum number of resident warps per multiprocessor which are on the Appendix F of the manual as my answer stated. The table is quite big to put here but I'll edit to include the maximum number of resident blocks per multiprocessor as so far it is the same across all compute capabilities.

Comment: That sounds better. The theoretical maximum is 8 x MP = 16 for @programmer. Thanks you for your effort.

Comment: @jmsu: So i can run only 16 blocks concurrently? Then, what is the use of providing 48 cores per multiprocessor if 40 of them are not used for a given kernel call

Comment: No one said one block per core, just maximum 8 blocks per multiprocessor but each block can occupy multiple cores.

Comment: @JMSU: Thanks for clarifying that the warps of a block can spread across different cores

Answer (score 3):

This comes down to semantics. What does "execute" and "running in parallel" really mean?

At a basic level, having 96 CUDA cores really means that you have a potential throughput of 96 results of calculations per cycle of the core clock.

A core is mainly an Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU), it performs basic arithmetic and logical operations. Aside from access to an ALU, a thread needs other resources, such as registers, shared memory and global memory to run. The GPU will keep many threads "in flight" to keep all these resources utilized to the fullest. The number of threads "in flight" will typically be much higher than the number of cores. On one hand, these threads can be seen as being "executed in parallel" because they are all consuming resources on the GPU at the same time. But on the other hand, most of them are actually waiting for something, such as data to arrive from global memory or for results of arithmetic to go through the pipelines in the cores. The GPU puts threads that are waiting for something on the "back burner". They are consuming some resources, but are they actually running? :)

Comment: I just read you answer and it got me thinking. I agree that the parallelism in the GPU depends on "threads doing something" which, I believe is not the same as "threads doing calculations or threads using cuda cores", am I right? So I think is some kind of marketing when NVIDIA says "GPU X has 1000000 cuda cores" so that consumers think it actually process that amount of data at the exactly same time? Which in fact could be possible or could be much more less depending on how the kernel was programmed and if is computation bounded or memory bounded?

Comment: @BRabbit27: An NVIDIA GPU is capable of processing, in the strictest sense of the word, many more threads at the same time than there are cores in the GPU. This is because each core has a pipeline through which tasks from many threads are traveling at the same time. This does, though, depend on the GPU being "saturated", meaning that it has warps eligible to be scheduled for each clock. The number of eligible warps depends on many factors, including the ones you mention.

Comment: @BRabbit27: NVIDIA does use the the word "core" to mean something different from its previously established meaning in the industry. So, yes, "CUDA cores" is a marketing term. It would be more accurate to call the cores, ALUs.

Answer (score 0):

The number of concurrently executed threads depends on your code and type of your CUDA device. For example Fermi has 2 thread schedulers for each stream multiprocessor and for current CPU clock will be scheduled 2 half-warps for calculation or memory load or transcendent function calculation. While one half-warp wait load or executed transcendent function CUDA cores may execute anything else. So you can get 96 threads on cores but if your code may get it. And, of course, you must have enough memory.