# Does cudpp only work for devices of a certain compute capability

Tags: cuda, cudpp

I want to use cudpp. I am curious if it only works for devices of a certain compute capability ?
If yes, what is the lower bound.

I found this error message in their hash table implementation code: 
"Error in cudppHashTable call in testHashTable (make sure your device is at                      least compute version 2.0\n"

I dont know which compute version they are referring to??

Comment: compute version 2.0 = compute capability 2.0. Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8473634/681865), you have a compute capability 2.1 device, so there is no hardware related impediment to you running the code you are asking about.

Comment: @talonmies: Actually, I am looking for an implementation that is not cc dependent

Comment: given compute capability 1.0 lacks *any* atomic operations, and compute capability 1.1 lacks shared memory atomic operations, I would very much doubt you could implement an efficient hash/histogram code which runs on those first generation devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For as far as I'm aware, there are no restrictions with regards to compute capability. There are some optimizations for cards with a Fermi architecture (sm_20) according to [the change logs](http://cudpp.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.0/doc/html/changelog.html).

CUDPP 2.0 [does however state](http://cudpp.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.0/doc/html/index.html) it only works for CUDA 3.0 or higher (and they advice to use versions higher than 3.2), but this has no direct relation to compute capability.

**Update:**

As found by the OP, there is indeed functionality which explicitly requires a 2.0 architecture, such as cudppHashTable. As per the [doc in the source](http://code.google.com/p/cudpp/source/browse/trunk/src/cudpp_hash/cudpp_hash.cpp) (line 206):

> The hash table implementation requires hardware capability 2.0 or
>   higher (64-bit atomic operations).

From the wording I would assume there are special cases in which a certain compute capability is required, but it is not a general requirement.

Comment: i was checking the code for their hash table implementation and they had the option to throw this error message : "Error in cudppHashTable call intestHashTable (make sure your device is at least compute version 2.0\n

Comment: Hmm, I was unaware of that, but having a look at their sources, the docs for the hastable indeed state "The hash table implementation requires hardware capability 2.0 or higher (64-bit atomic operations)".

Comment: so how would u implement a hash table on GPU

Comment: That would be a different question altogether and not one we should discuss as part of this question.